How to print a string that contains "<" character in PHP?
For some reason I am unable to print this string: 'ggukjbgfjI:2<EiK6'. There is no escape for "<" that I am aware of.
<?php
$x = 'ggukjbgfjI:2<';
$y = 'EiK6';
$z = 'ggukjbgfjI:2<EiK6';
echo $x;
echo $y;
echo "<br><br>";
echo $z;
?>


It is printed, but if viewed with a browser it would be parsed as sign to open a tag. See with (rightclick show source in browser). You can escape it for HTML like echo htmlspecialchars($z);.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

If you view page source in your browser, you will see that your code actually outputs:
ggukjbgfjI:2<EiK6<br><br>ggukjbgfjI:2<EiK6

But in the browser you only see:
ggukjbgfjI:2
ggukjbgfjI:2

So what gives? This is because < is the opening character of an <html> tag, meaning that the browser is parsing everything inside it as HTML code until it meets a > character.
The solution to this, is to encode the < as an HTML entity, ie. &lt;
So if you have the code:
$x = 'ggukjbgfjI:2&lt;';
$y = 'EiK6';
$z = 'ggukjbgfjI:2&lt;EiK6';
echo $x;
echo $y;
echo "<br><br>";
echo $z;

It will output, as you'd expect:
ggukjbgfjI:2<EiK6

ggukjbgfjI:2<EiK6

There is also a built in PHP function htmlspecialchars to encode special characters for you automatically, so that your output won't be confused with any special HTML characters. Eg:
$x = 'ggukjbgfjI:2<';
$y = 'EiK6';
$z = 'ggukjbgfjI:2<EiK6';
echo htmlspecialchars($x);
echo htmlspecialchars($y);
echo "<br><br>";
echo htmlspecialchars($z);

